# how do I log the body in multiparty

Tags: node.js, express, multipart

I am using node-multiparty, how do I log the body of the POST request?

```
app.post("/submit", function(httpRequest, httpResponse, next){

    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.on("part", function(part){
        if(part.filename)
        {
            var FormData = require("form-data");
            var request = require("request")
            var form = new FormData();

            form.append("thumbnail", part, {filename: part.filename,contentType: part["content-type"]});

            var r = request.post("http://localhost:7070/store", { "headers": {"transfer-encoding": "chunked"} }, function(err, res, body){ 
                httpResponse.send(res);
            });

            r._form = form
        }
    })

    form.on("error", function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })

    form.parse(httpRequest);    

});
```

Comment: You probably can't, as `multiparty` parses the request body as a stream, meaning it (most likely) won't be collecting the entire body content.

Comment: Just curious, why are you handling one multipart request (which presumably has multiple "file" blobs in its body) by sending another multipart request (which has just a single part: one of the "file" blobs) to a different service and then sending the response back as soon as the first "file" blob has been POSTed to the other URL? It seems like you could just proxy the incoming request straight to your other service.